# Reference Error trying to use Cloud command in Sailsjs app

Tags: sails.js, google-cloud-sdk

I am following the Sails.js tutorial here: https://courses.platzi.com/classes/1273-sails-js/10748-using-cloud-stk/ and am at the point of adding a cloud.js file to use the Cloud SDK to access the api endpoints.

I have successfully run `scripts/rebuild-cloud-sdk.js` which generated

app/assets/js/cloud.setup.js which contains:

```
Cloud.setup({

  /* eslint-disable */
  methods: {"confirmEmail":{"verb":"GET","url":"/email/confirm","args":["token"]},"logout":{"verb":"GET","url":"/api/v1/account/logout","args":[]},"updatePassword":{"verb":"PUT","url":"/api/v1/account/update-password","args":["password"]},"updateProfile":{"verb":"PUT","url":"/api/v1/account/update-profile","args":["fullName","emailAddress"]},"updateBillingCard":{"verb":"PUT","url":"/api/v1/account/update-billing-card","args":["stripeToken","billingCardLast4","billingCardBrand","billingCardExpMonth","billingCardExpYear"]},"login":{"verb":"PUT","url":"/api/v1/entrance/login","args":["emailAddress","password","rememberMe"]},"signup":{"verb":"POST","url":"/api/v1/entrance/signup","args":["emailAddress","password","fullName"]},"sendPasswordRecoveryEmail":{"verb":"POST","url":"/api/v1/entrance/send-password-recovery-email","args":["emailAddress"]},"updatePasswordAndLogin":{"verb":"POST","url":"/api/v1/entrance/update-password-and-login","args":["password","token"]},"deliverContactFormMessage":{"verb":"POST","url":"/api/v1/deliver-contact-form-message","args":["emailAddress","topic","fullName","message"]},"destroyOneEntity":{"verb":"DELETE","url":"/api/v1/entities/destroy-one-entity","args":["id"]}}
  /* eslint-enable */

});
```

but in sails console, when I run `Cloud.destroyOneEntity.with({ id: 3 }).log()`

it returns:

`ReferenceError: Cloud is not defined`

Comment: Are you seeing the issue in a newly-generated Sails project that was created using the "Web app" template?

Comment: I figured out, i was attempting to use cloud in sails console in terminal. Still not sure why that doesn't work. but it behaved normally in the in-browser console.